# run part of an event once and run other part several times

Tags: jquery

```
$(".a").on("click",function(){
        $("b").stop(true, true).slideUp(500);
        $(this).next("c").stop(true, true).slideDown(500);
    });
```

I want when user clicks "a", this line (line 1) run only once:

```
$("b").stop(true, true).slideUp(500);
```

but this line (line 2) run unlimited:

```
$(this).next("c").stop(true, true).slideDown(500);
```

Thats mean, when user clicks "a" again, line 1 not run but line 2 be run.
How? I try this but not work:

```
$(".a").on("click",function(event){
            $("b").stop(true, true).slideUp(500);
            $(this).next("c").stop(true, true).slideDown(500);
            $(this).off( event );
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to get cleaner code and better convey the meaning.

```
$(".a")
   .one("click", function () { alert("Only once!"); })
   .click(function () { alert("Always!"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set a flag using `data` when the user clicked the button:

```
$(".a").on("click",function(){
    if (!$(this).data('clicked')) {
        $("b").stop(true, true).slideUp(500);
        $(this).data('clicked', true);
    }
    $(this).next("c").stop(true, true).slideDown(500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a class to flag execution

```
$(".a").on("click",function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('clickedOnce')){
           $("b").stop(true, true).slideUp(500);
           $(this).addClass('clickedOnce');
        }
        $(this).next("c").stop(true, true).slideDown(500);
    });
```